# A Proof using Telescopic Sum: $a_1=3,\,2a_n = 1+a_{n-1};\;n\ge 2.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

$ a_1 = 3,\,  2a_n = 1+a_{n-1}; \;n \ge 2 $

Prove that  $ a_n = 1 + 2^{2-n};\; n\in Z^+ $ using Telescopic Series.

I was able to do with Mathematical induction, need some help with Telescopic series.

Comment: What they probably mean by "using telescopic series" is that $$2^na_n-2^{n-1}a_{n-1}=2^{n-1}$$ hence $$2^na_n-2a_1=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2^k=2^n-2$$ that is, $$2^na_n=2^n-2+2a_1=2^n+4$$ and you are done.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. By multiplying 
$$
2a_n = 1+a_{n-1}
$$
by $2^{n-1}$ one gets
$$
2^n a_n = 2^{n-1}+2^{n-1} a_{n-1}
$$ or
$$
2^n a_n -2^{n-1} a_{n-1}= 2^{n-1}
$$ then one has *telescoping terms* when summing with respect to $n$.